# HIVE: apply delimiter until a specified column

Tags: hadoop, datatable, hive, delimiter

I am trying to move data from a file into a hive table. The data in the file looks something like this:-

StringA StringB StringC StringD StringE

where each string is separated by a space. The problem is that i want separate columns for StringA, StringB and StringC and one column for StringD onwards i.e. StringD and String E should be part of the same column. If i use 
`ROW DELIMITED BY FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '`, Hive would produce separate columns for StringD and StringE. (StringD and StringE contain space within themselves whereas other strings do not contain spaces within themselves)

Is there any special syntax in hive to achieve this or do i need to pre-process my data file in some way?

Comment: You could just import the data into you hive table using a space delimiter and then concat `StringD` & `StringE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expresion
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-ApacheWeblogData
you can define when use space as delimiter and when part of data

Comment: Do you mean i need to specify "“output.format.string” = “%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s”? The problem is that i might have variable number of strings after StringC.

Comment: it is not problem in end of string - just set (.*) for last field.

Comment: So i created the table like :-

create table tab1 (col1 string, col2 string, col3 string, col4 string) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("input.regex" = "([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (-|\\[[^\\]]*\\]) ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") (-|[0-9]*) (-|[0-9]*)(?: ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\"))?",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s .*");

and tried to load data by the command:- 
load data inpath '/location/of/filedata.txt' into table tab1;

the commands were successful but the table is filled with all NULLs.

Comment: `create table tab1 (col1 string, col2 string, col3 string, col4 string) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("input.regex" = "([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (.*)?")` it is enough

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the use of the output.format.string then?

Comment: for change or clean data. for example if you want drop second column `"%1$s %3$s %4$s"`